# Get alert if my email is read issue with gmail and yahoo

Tags: php, python, ruby, email, get

I need to build a functionality in my app ,

If I send email to users , if they read my email I need to get notification.

So I am sending an "HTML email" to my users with an embedded image , If I get a GET request to my image then I will handle it to get notification.

I am sending email using my yahoo mail using TunderBird client , using insert HTML.

If this worked fine I will automate it in my app.

I am sending this email to users. when I open this HTML file local browser its giving a GET request , in my server's log  I can see that GET request.

But my problem is when I am sending this HTML to a Gmail or Yahoomail , its showing my HTML file , but that src url is getting replaced with google urls , So I am not getting any GET request to my server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>If you read this mail , I will get notification</h2>

<img src="http://mywebsite.com/1.jpg" alt="my_image" >

</body>
</html>
```

In google email I checked original source , My code is changed to the following.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
    <h2>If you read this mail , I will get notification</h2>

    <img src="cid:part1.06010807.03070606@yahoo.com" alt="Mountain View">

  </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this , Help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with Gmail anymore and Google changed it exactly for this reason, so you can't track their users anymore.

I doubt you can do anything about this, considering that they really don't want you to do it.

You can read more on [Google's blog post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.ro/2013/12/images-now-showing.html).

Comment: Thats OK, what about yahoo and some other custom email services like godaddy email accounts..?